# confidence intervals for android gps lat/long accuracy

Tags: android, geospatial

I have a database of lat/longs generated using [`getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude%28%29) from the Android API. These are in decimal degrees and have varying levels of precision (some are to 7 decimal places, some to 11, etc).

Is there an easy way to back out confidence intervals for the location based on the number of decimal places? Or is backing out accuracy not feasible one the data point has already been captured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you've got is recorded lats and longs then you're out of luck. Seven decimal places is quite a lot of precision anyway (I think you'll find that 1/10,000,000th of a degree isn't very far at all, sub centimeter, and is already more precise than the GPS receiver is capable of).

The GPS receiver is most likely to have output HDOP and VDOP figures (horizontal and vertical dilutions of precision), but there's not way to deduce what these were from the recorded lat and long AFAIK.

If the values are timestamped and for a moving device then its likely that the numbers are noisy, and it would be possible to filter them. This would smooth out the numbers, and you could then work out the standard deviation of the raw data away from the mean. Could give a semi-useful answer.

Or you could do what SatNav systems do; if you know something of the means by which the device is moving (i.e. in a car?) then its reasonable to assume that it is somewhere on the means of transport (e.g. the road). SatNavs take the GPS reading and correct it by referencing their inbuilt road map.